# Вывести родительский термин во Views (Drupal)

Tags: drupal, views

Настраиваю экспорт данных в Drupal с помощью "Views Data Export". Нужно во вьюс для каждой строчки товара вывести не только текущий термин, но и всех родителей в формате "parent/subparent/term" (хотя бы одного родителя, у меня вложенность всего 1 уровень).

Понимаю, что нужно добавить поле с родительским термином, а потом перезаписать вывод родного термина в нужном мне формате. Но не пойму как добавить поле с родителем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Добавить в "Связи"**:

- Содержимое: Термины таксономии материала
- Термин таксономии: Родительский термин

**Добавить поле:**

- Термин таксономии (Связь - родительский термин)

Теперь можно скрыть это поле и переопределить вывод родного термина таксономии, вставив в него значение родительского термина.